# What is the maximum gift values between joint households

Tags: united-states, gift-tax

I understand there is an annual tax free gift limit of $14,000 (2016)

Is this number impacted by filing status?

If my wife and I (filing jointly) wanted to give my brother and his wife (filing jointly) a maximum gift would that be $56,000 / year?
(I give 14k to my brother and 14k to his wife, and then *my wife* gives 14k to my brother and 14k to his wife?)

Or how would the cap be calculated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If my wife and I (filing jointly) wanted to give my brother and his
>   wife (filing jointly) a maximum gift would that be $56,000 / year? (I
>   give 14k to my brother and 14k to his wife, and then my wife gives 14k
>   to my brother and 14k to his wife?)

That is almost exactly right.

The only things that are incorrect are:

- it doesn't matter if they are family
- it doesn't matter what the filing status of the recipient.

the IRS does have a [FAQ regarding gift taxes](https://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Frequently-Asked-Questions-on-Gift-Taxes):

> **How many annual exclusions are available?**
>
> The annual exclusion applies to gifts to each donee. In other words,
>   if you give each of your children $11,000 in 2002-2005, $12,000 in
>   2006-2008, $13,000 in 2009-2012 and $14,000 on or after January 1,
>   2013, the annual exclusion applies to each gift. The annual exclusion
>   for 2014, 2015, and 2016 is $14,000.
>
> **What if my spouse and I want to give away property that we own together?**
>
> You are each entitled to the annual exclusion amount on the gift.
>   Together, you can give $22,000 to each donee (2002-2005) or $24,000
>   (2006-2008), $26,000 (2009-2012) and $28,000 on or after January 1,
>   2013 (including 2014, 2015, and 2016).

Comment: Also be aware that any gift over that amount can be deducted from the estate tax lifetime exemption, which is $5.34M in 2015. If your estate will be less than that, you should be able to gift more than $14k tax free. https://turbotax.intuit.com/tax-tools/tax-tips/Tax-Planning-and-Checklists/The-Gift-Tax-Made-Simple/INF12127.html

Comment: And to add clarification - the 5.34M is per person. I'd hate think OP has a $6M net worth and misinterpreted that number. So far, he's fine up to $10.68M between him and the missus.